# Android mnifest file merging error tool:allowBackup=true

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

I am facing merging issue in android manifest file can anybody tell me how i can solve this issue.

Manifest code

```
<application 
tools:replace="android:allowBackup=true"
android:allowBackup="true">
```

Error

```
/Users/Desktop/iOSGit/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-46:19 Error:
tools:replace specified at line:27 for attribute android:allowBackup=true, but no new value specified
/Users/Desktop/iOSGit/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Validation failed, exiting
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `"`, is that just a typo in your question? Or do you have that missing in your file as well? Could you also post your whole `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup"/>
```